# Swift - Delete single record from database

Tags: database, swift, core-data

I'm trying to delete a single record from the database.

```
if let items=fetchedResult{
            print(items.count) //this always prints "1", so it's working well
            for item:NSManagedObject in items{
                println(item) //this prints the only element found. Also working well
                println(sender.view!.restorationIdentifier!) //the restorationIdentifier matches with the id from the object in the database. Also working well
                managagedContext.deleteObject(item) //<-- THIS is what is not working
                sender.view?.removeFromSuperview() //removing the view well
            }
        }else{
            print("Could not delete \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
        }
```

As said in the comments, the line `managagedContext.deleteObject(item)` is not working, I'm not getting any error, it just doesn't delete the object in the database.

I've been searching for 2 days and found nothing. I hope you can help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you save the context after the delete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Apple's doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/deleteObject:) for `deleteObject`

> Specifies an object that should be removed from its persistent store **when changes are committed**.

You need to call `context.save` to make your changes persistent. [save documentation says that:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/save:)

> If a context’s parent store is a persistent store coordinator, then changes are committed to the external store

Also: [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13990404/225503) shows the details of calling save:, and managing the NSError